# Xamarin Forms IOS, API Request return The Internet connection appears to be offline

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project for IOS, when executing a request to any API it sends me the following error:

*"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={…"*

My method:

```
public async Task<T> PostResponse<T>(string weburl, string jsonstring) where T : class
  {
     try
         {
            GetDefaultHeaderBearer();
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(weburl, new StringContent(jsonstring, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            string jsonResult = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
               
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           throw new Exception(e.Message);
         }
  }
```

My Api's server is hosted on a local linux server which I can access from the wifi, within my Iphone device (No simulator) I can access the apis from safari, but the xamarin app returns that error when trying to make any request.

My development environment is Windows 10 pro with Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.2.
Nuget version:

- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2125. Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0.
  NetStandard.Library 2.0.3.

Comment: Google returns **many** hits for that error message, have you read any of them for possible fixes?

Comment: @Jason I already spent many hours on possible google solutions, but it is not working.

Comment: @Jason Any help you can give would be welcome.

Comment: Try to update VS to the latest version to see if problem persists, please refer to the issue : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6762#issuecomment-528223653.

Answer (score 0):

Set App Transport Security in your.plist;

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: It did not work, I have added this configuration in info.plist, but it keeps failing me.